# What is an easy Mylyn task repository to use for a small (~40 devs) project?

Tags: eclipse, repository, ganymede, mylyn

I'm currently the only developer using Eclipse Mylyn integration (I'm the experimental one). I have two repositories configured - Bugzilla, which the project uses for internal bug tracking and a Local repository. I use the Local repo for organizing the stories I am working on for the iteration.

What I'd like to do is make that Local repo shareable so that other developers could perhaps use it. If developers like it, we could adopt Mylyn as a project standard. Which kind of repository would you devs recommend? The requirements are "free" (as in "speech" and "beer") and "awesome" (as in "The Rapture"). It would need to be deployed on a Windows server and share resources with other services (so not too resource intensive). Simple to configure would be nice as well, since I'm just exploring this on my own time. Perhaps a separate Bugzilla instance?

Thanks!
LES

Comment: Love "free" and "awesome" as requirements.

Comment: Do you really think today that a project with 40 software developers is small? How many developers would it take to make medium, large or huge project?

Comment: 400 = medium; 4,000 = large; 40,000 = extra large; i now work on a team with a total of 3 developers. i don't even have a term for that level of smallness.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why don't you simply use your original Bugzilla instance?

Personally, I'd consider it tedious and useless to separate tasks and bugs.

Comment: This is what we actually did! It's working great for me. We have some developers on the team who don't seem to like technology or upgrading, haven't enabled Mylyn in Eclipse (even though I packaged a new Galileo with the plugins + defaults set up). They just use the email interface.

Comment: Good practical suggestion. +1

Answer (score 8):

Not answering the OP, but other people might be interested: I am using a local repository stored in my DropBox so that I can have tasks propagate to all my working machines.

This works okay, but you really have to be careful about having more than one Eclipse instance operating on the same Mylyn directory.  Mylyn stuff seems to be mostly (exclusively?) saved to disk when you close Eclipse, so if you have two instances open you are likely to overwrite things unintentionally.  Sometimes this is recoverable through Dropbox history, sometimes not.  I'm still using this method without much trouble but it takes vigilance.

Eclipse Preferences -> Mylyn -> Tasks -> Advanced -> Data directory

Comment: Hi! How did you configure the local repository for Mylyn?

Comment: @furtelwart: Edited my answer to include that info.

Answer (score 6):

I really recommend [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/). It is free and based on Ruby on Rails. There's a [Mylyn plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/redmin-mylyncon/) for the integration. For sure, it is just awesome (the entire Redmine.org site is simply running Redmine, so check it out) with all sorts of Ajax goodness and clean professional looking interface.

Answer (score 5):

You could setup a [MantisBT bugtracking system](http://www.mantisbt.org/), with the appropriate [Mylyn-Mantis Repository Connector](http://mylyn-mantis.wiki.sourceforge.net/).

Since Mantis is a bit more complete than Bugzilla (when it comes to features), you could define separate issues with custom field, for your tasks. It also does [support Roadmap](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt:features:roadmap).

Comment: this one had two votes (including one of mine), so i accepted it. however, all of the answers are valid.

Answer (score 1):

From free ones, you can use Bugzilla, Mantis or Trac (which I was able to get running on Windows, but there are many hostings available too).

Free for two users is FogBugz (and Mylyn connector is free for this Fogbugz edition ... see my profile :-) )